# SaaS location of admin URL

Tags: saas, subdomain

### Background

I work at a SaaS company where you get a site when you signup.

If the company's url is saas.com this could be a list of clients:

```
abc.saas.com
mysite.saas.com
so.saas.com
```

Currently, each of our clients has to go to /admin to get to his admin panel.

```
abc.saas.com/admin
mysite.saas.com/admin
so.saas.com/admin
```

The thing is that services like Clicktale that track users by recording them, limit the amount of subdomains you can track. If you want more subdomains, you have to pay more.

Because of this we are analyzing the possibility of migrating to `admin.saas.com` as a single subdomain for all admin panels.

**Which are the pros and cons of having several /admin subdomains VS a single admin subdomain?**

### Considerations

- SSL is already solved, we have a wildcard certificate
- We could keep a 301 redirect from /admin to the admin.saas.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pros to have a single domain (admin.saas.com):

- Users having more subscriptions can manage subdomains much easier (they don't have to navigate to a different URL)
- Your documentation and videos will be easier to understand with a specific address. Links with placeholders like {yourdomain}.saas.com/admin make clients think.
- Firewall rules could be set up easier in a complex architecture

We had to make the same decision while developing our SaaS/PaaS product few months ago and we are happy with this implementations. According to your scenario, I cannot see any cons.

Comment: Cons: the single admin is a specific known address that is more vulnerable to brute force and denial of service attacks.